# Trigonometric Identity Problem - Cos Tan and Sin

Tags: trigonometry

I have been going through my lecture notes for a structures question (the solution of a 2nd order ode for a buckling problem) when I came across a very weird trigonometric simplification which I just cannot get my head around. Could anyone shed any light on this?[image]

Further down the page, there is another similar simplification, but this one seems to be incorrect:

[image]

Testing some random values, the simplification is incorrect unless I replace the C/2 with a C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This simplification is correct as

$$\cos t+\tan 2t\sin t=\cos t+\frac{\sin 2t}{\cos 2t}\sin t=\frac{\cos t\cos 2t+\sin t\sin 2t}{\cos 2t}=\frac{\cos(2t-t)}{\cos2t} $$

Similarly, $$-\sin t+\tan2t\cos t=-\sin t+\frac{\sin2t\cos t}{\cos2t}=\frac{\sin2t\cos t-\sin t\cos2t}{\cos2t}=\frac{\sin(2t-t)}{\cos2t}$$

Put $t=\frac{\mu'L}4$

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get the second one after your first answer, however as I said I don't get the C/2 coefficient on the RHS, just a C. Can you confirm this is correct?

Comment: @KeirSimmons, also $\mu$ in the LHS got removed

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos \dfrac{A}{2}+\tan A \sin \dfrac{A}{2}$$

$$=\cos\dfrac{A}{2}+\dfrac{\sin A}{\cos A} \sin \dfrac{A}{2}$$

$$=\cos \dfrac{A}{2}(1+2\dfrac{\sin^2 \frac{A}{2}}{\cos A})$$

$$=\cos \dfrac{A}{2}(\dfrac{\cos A+ 2 \sin^2 \frac{A}{2}}{\cos A})$$

$\cos A=1-\sin^2 \dfrac{A}{2} \implies(\dfrac{\cos A+ 2 \sin^2 \frac{A}{2}}{\cos A})=\dfrac{1}{\cos A}$

And the final expression becomes: $\cos \dfrac{A}{2} \cdot \dfrac{1}{\cos A}=\sec A \cdot \cos \dfrac{A}{2}$